# Remote access db on hosting

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, web-hosting

I have paid the php / mysql hosting. There, as part of the package i got cpanel. Nice :) 
Now, using "phpmyadmin" i have created a database, added users and everything. I hate using "phpmyadmin", i used on "Navicat" so far, so i want to connect my desktop "Navicat" to remote database.

This is what i did:
In "remote mysql" secion of the "cpanel" i have added "www.mysite.tk", my home ip address, even the "%".
In "Navicat" i tried connecting to "mysite.tk" over standard port 3306, using positively correct uname / pass combination - no luck.

Tech support isn't responding and i have to solve this asap so i wanted to ask you if i did something wrong or allowing me to connect from desktop directly to my remote db is entirely up to the hosting company and their terms?

Comment: Why do you think mysql is allowed to connect from outside on that hosting?

Comment: Hmm i don't know. I'm good at programming, administrating isn't my strong side so that's why i have to ask :$ I'm not sure even if remote db connecting is "granted"

Comment: `telnet yourhost 3306`

Comment: zerkms: "Could not open connection to the host on port 3306" :\ Is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: Are you sure you have added the right IP address as Access Host?

Comment: yes. Checked it on the internet.